# "www" subdomain stripped from "website" field in profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks

When the "website" field in a personal profile starts with "www.", the profile page shows a shortened URL without the subdomain. I assume this is to improve readability. However, it is technically wrong - they are not the same URLs. From a usability perspective, it might be okay to ask if the "www" may be removed; breaking the URL without warning is confusing.

The problem is not as grave for users with high reputation, as on their profiles the shortened URL is actually a clickable link to the correct URL. However, for new users, it isn't - only the broken URL is displayed. Maybe the profile for a new user should show the unmodified URL, or completely hide the URL until it can be displayed correctly.

For now, I have set up a domain that redirects to the correct URL. Is there any workaround that allows me to actually display the correct URL? Entering the "www." twice would work, but would probably break the clickable link later...

Comment: Fun fact: a huge percentage of government sites where I live simply won't work without the "www".

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn My university websites are worse, some only half work with the www, and for some websites the www is only there if you ware using the internal network. It's all crazy.

Comment: Mine also happens to be a university website. Since it seems to be so in vogue to drop the "www", some might consider this to be a bug in the server setup...